# How to add a custom background to a QR Code

Tags: android

I created a an app in `Android` which generates a `QR Code`. Now I want to customize that `QR Code` by giving a custom background to the `QR Code`. I used `zxing Library` to generate `QR Code`. Anybody please help.

Comment: This may help. http://mashable.com/2011/04/18/qr-code-design-tips/#wRSTKuwb2OqY

Comment: What do you mean a custom background? In what regards do you want to customize it?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: A QR code is meant to be consumed by a machine and that works best if you keep it standard.

Comment: Custom background means we can select an image from our mobile and set it as the background of our QR Code.